# to enable dot in html keypad input

Tags: android, html

I am designing a website. Dealing with an HTML page where a user enters decimal numbers. Let's say I will ask for their height and he has to enter it as 5.6 feet. The problem I am having is the input format on the Android keypad. My code for input format is:

```
<input type="number" lang="en-150" id="height1" name="total" value="" placeholder="In feet">
```

Now when the android keyboard appears it does not contains the dot(.) instead it just contains numbers 1,2,3,...,9,0. So user can't enter 5.6 instead 56.

I have also used:

```
type="number" lang="en-150"
```

and:

```
type="number" step="0.01"
```

and:

```
type="decimal"
```

Despite all, the keyboard is still simple. I have also checked stack flow and codes on other forums but nothing helps me out.

Comment: What does this have to do with Android?

Comment: I am actually talking about Android keypad, sorry not to mention, have added it. When user opens html website on the mobile phone the keypad does not contain a dot for fraction input.

Comment: You will use a browser isnt it? Which browser are you talking about? Did you try other browsers? Try them all!

Comment: In all browsers, it is doing the same behaviour. I don't think scrolling browsers can change android keypad.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with:

```html
<form action="">
  <input id="height1" type="text" name="total" pattern="[0-9]+(\.([0-9]+)?)?"  value="" placeholder="In feet">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

However, the user can insert any character after the validation

To solve this, you will need use javascript and check before any keyDown click

Comment: type="text" actually opens the qwerty keypad. It is already working for the qwerty keypad. Running this code wtih type="number" still same only numbers on numeric pad.